# Can I download my app code from Ionic Platform?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I publish my app to ionic platform. Then I removed code by accident on my mac. Can I download my code from platform?

Comment: Did you develop and publish an app without using a version control system??

Comment: sebaferreras, i used git but without push. I know it's not smart, but now, do I have some way to return my code with ionic platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

> If you need to recover your app files, enter your App ID below and
>   click recover. It will download a ZIP containing your latest app
>   upload.

Login to [Ionic Platform](https://ionic.io/platform).

Then go to [Your Ionic Data](https://apps.ionic.io/settings/data) (Recover your App), enter your app ID and download your latest app upload.